# Почему в Linux на одном ядре время простоя больше uptime?

Tags: linux, cygwin

Вот (постоянно трудится Trasmission):

```
$ uname -a
Linux HOSTNAME 2.6.31.14_7820 #22 SMP Wed Sep 21 16:29:23 CST 2011 armv6l GNU/Linux

$ uptime
06:15:21 up 37 min,  X users,  load average: 0.19, 0.37, 0.49

$ cat /proc/uptime
92561.02 127032.13


$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 5 (v6l)
processor       : 0
BogoMIPS        : 299.00

processor       : 1
BogoMIPS        : 299.00

Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb02
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : Oxsemi NAS
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000
```

Хотя в proc(5) написано:

*/proc/uptime*

This file contains two numbers: the uptime of the system (seconds), and the amount of time spent in idle process (seconds).

В Cygwin на двухядерном процессоре (практически простаивает):

```
 $ cat /proc/uptime
 431622.39 418535.48
```

Comment: Вот в cygwin у вас странная сумма. хотя она же небось эмулируется, cygwin это же не linux. А в linux выдается сумма простоя по обоим ядрам, поэтому она гораздо больше аптайма.

Comment: Так у меня что? На 2-х ядрах Linux крутится? "Слона-то я и не приметил"

Comment: Нужно было немного подольше погуглить. В паре мест всё-таки было сказано, что простой считается суммарно по всем ядрам.

Comment: Ну лично я когда коммент написал даже не гуглил, просто заглянул в исходники ядра. Так обычно гораздо проще понять что представлено в /proc